# What kind of data is appropriate for probability density plots?

Tags: density-function

Is it appropriate to use a probability density plot on calculated data?  For instance, in ArcMap I have several gridded data sets that I use to calculate a final gridded data set?  Is it appropriate to use a probability density plot on this data?  I wouldn't consider it experimental - I do not believe I am sampling from some population, P, but rather using measured values (or estimated values) to generate another estimated value.  Can a probability density plot still be used?  I have found it is the clearest method to visualize my data, even if not entirely appropriate.

OP added as comment October 28, 2015 [minute editing Nick Cox]

The main reasons I have for choosing density plots over histograms in this very case, are that the density plots (from `ggplot`) are less muddied and more clearly indicate areas of overlap as well as the tails of the calculated variables compared with the histograms I have been able to generate from the same graphics package and other similar ones. Therefore, they seem to give a better understanding of my results (calculated for different formulations/combinations of inputs) then using the standard-bearer, histograms.

Answer (score 2):

I presume this means the result of some density estimate, e.g. from a kernel density calculation. I see absolutely no reason why not. It's just a smooth representation of your (calculated) data. In principle you would presumably not object to a histogram, which is just (equivalent to) a different estimate of the density function. Any kind of smoothing can thought of as an attempt to get at the main signal in the data: you are not committed as a matter of dogma to the idea that everything you do has to be interpreted in terms of a larger population or a generating process.

Orthogonally to that, I will just add that too many users accept the default from their software as the estimate, which is not a good procedure, even if the default is based on some sensible rule of thumb or on cross-validation. Any density estimate you take seriously needs a little sensitivity analysis in terms of changing kernel width, perhaps kernel type, and very often also what is done if the variable is bounded above and/or below.

For example, a common default that bites especially when a variable is positive, or non-negative, and positively skewed is that probability is smeared below zero, and then ignored. It's also common in such cases that the density is under-smoothed for high values and over-smoothed for low values.

I'd add that quantile plots don't require any arbitrary choices at all and with a little effort reveal level, spread, skew, tail behaviour, gaps, ties and outliers. Density plots blur some of these details. So, if you have reservations about histograms (as do most practising data analysts) there are other kinds of graphs too.